# Ruby https with ca certification does not work while it worked with curl

Tags: ruby, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, net-http

In ruby, I try to do a ssl connection to a nginx server I setup locally, with an auto-signed certificate. My code is :

```
require "net/http"
require "net/https"
require "openssl"
require "uri"
require "pp"

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/")
response = Net::HTTP.start(
  "localhost",
  443,
  {
    :use_ssl => true,
    :key => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/home/gg/crt/client.key")),
    :cert => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("/home/gg/crt/client.crt")),
    :ca_file => "/home/gg/crt/ca.pem",
    :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
    :verify_depth => 5,
  }
) do |http|
      http.request(request)
end
puts response.inspect
puts response.body
```

When I run it it return

```
/home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from /home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from /home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from /home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /home/gg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:583:in `start'
    from testso.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

But I have the correct result if I run it with curl:

```
curl https://localhost --key crt/client.key --cert crt/client.crt --cacert crt/ca.pem
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel dumb but figured out the problem.

When generating the different certificates I left some fields blank. 
It seems that openssl detected this certificate as "looking" autosigned.

Thus if we use OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER the connection fails

So to be sure that the certificate is well generated using the CA you can do :
`openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt server.crt`
(and same command with client.crt)

if we get

```
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

The certificate is detected as autosigned and it fails

if we get

```
 Signature ok
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

To possibly help others, here is a working solution with Ruby 2.0, for an HTTP GET.

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse('https://your_url.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version]=nil
http.use_ssl = true
http.ca_path='/etc/pki/tls/certs/'
http.ca_file='/etc/pki/tls/certs/YOUR_CERT_CHAIN_FILE'
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("YOUR_CERT)_FILE"))
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("YOUR_KEY_FILE"))

#SSLv3 is cracked, and often not allowed
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2

#### This is IMPORTANT
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

#Crete the GET request
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
#Add Headers, if needed
request.add_field 'X_REMOTE_USER', 'USER_NAME'
request.add_field 'Accept', '*'

#Get Response
response = http.request(request)

#Review Response
puts response.body
```

Comment: Indeed it worked. But the point was to not set SSL:: VERIFY_NONE. Doing so, you downgrade security.

Comment: as @GPif stated, `SSL::VERIFY_NONE` obviates the any of the `ca` settings.